# Uploading to AWS S3 using a presigned URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I need to upload files to S3 from a machine that *must* have its clock set incorrectly, and the offset from the correct time will vary.  You can apparently do this by specifying the `X-Amz-Date` header (setting it to the current actual time) and uploading using query string authorization.  The `aws-sdk` Ruby gem does not expose this parameter in its `presigned_url` method, so I'm trying to do it using the `aws-sigv4` gem.  My `PUT`s, however, are being rejected with `403 Unauthorized` errors.

Here is the code I've tried:

```ruby
def upload_file_with_time(file, file_path, expires_in_seconds, time)
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

  obj = s3_bucket.object(file_path)

  signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
    service: 's3',
    region: region,
    access_key_id: access_key_id,
    secret_access_key: secret_access_key
  )

  pre_signed_url = signer.presign_url(
    http_method: 'PUT',
    url: obj.public_url,
    expires_in: expires_in_seconds,
    time: time
  )

  Net::HTTP.start(pre_signed_url.host) do |http|
    http.send_request("PUT", pre_signed_url.request_uri, file, "content-type": "")
  end
end
```

The code generates a presigned URL like this:

`https://XXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/testing/89254661-24de-4bc7-b6e1-7d0018213735.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXX%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190301T213824Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXX` (sensitive information has been redacted with `XXXXX`).

I get a `403 Unauthorized` from `http.send_request` when I try to upload to this endpoint.  If I hit the URL with a post from `curl`, I see this as the beginning of the XML response:

```xml
<?xml version=“1.0”?>
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the clock at least deterministically/predictably incorrect?

Comment: The offset will vary.  I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @JoshuaMcGee did you ever figure out the issue? I am running into the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

> I need to upload files to S3 from a machine that must have its clock set incorrectly.

Is the time in past or future? Though the possibility is miniscule, this might be causing issues (nothing in the docs indicates the same though).

However, I see that you are using the `Net::HTTP` package and making a **raw PUT request** and the method you are using for generating the presigned URL does not look very convincing to me because of the `obj.public_url` thing.

Anyways, I did have a requirement like this (presigned URL upload but without the 'incorrect time on the machine' part). This is the guide I used and it worked:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html

There is a working code on that page (not pasting it here because it might change in future) which worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I saw that guide too, and it works fine when using the `presigned_url` method from the `aws-sdk` gem.  I cannot use that method, however, as it does not expose the X-Amz-Date parameter.  If there is a different URL I should be hitting with the raw PUT request, I'm interested to learn it. The offset will vary, but past/future does not seem to be a factor in getting it to work.